# Universal-Image-Loader Custom FileNameGenerator based on local file name

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image Loader to display images downloaded from a URI or already available in a disk cache implementation.

I want to display music album covers, but more than one track might have the same URI for a cover (i.e. tracks from the same album). I want that even if the image is the same it's stored each time for each different track with the track name, because I want users to be able to replace the default covers with a custom one, even for each single track.

**For instance**

- 01 - Track 01.mp3
- 02 - Track 02.mp3

Belong to the same album and the cover URI is `http://something/img.jpg`, on disk cache I want to have

- 01 - Track 01.jpg
- 02 - Track 02.jpg

even if it's the same image.

So I've coded a `FileNameGenerator` that stores a `Set` of hashes for each `Uri`, where the hash is the SHA-1 of the absolute path of the file.

Here is my implementation:

```
public MyFileNameGenerator(String ext) {
    super();
    this.ext = ext;
}

HashMap<String,HashSet<String>> names = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

@Override
public String generate(String imageUri) {
    if(imageUri==null) return null;
    if (imageUri.startsWith("file:///")) {
        return FilenameUtils.removeExtension(Uri.parse(imageUri)
                .getLastPathSegment()) + "."+ext;
    }
    //How to recognize the correct hash?
    //return FilenameUtils.removeExtension(Data.currentFiles
    //      .get(names.get(imageUri)).getName()) + "." + ext;
}

public void setTrackData(String uri, String hash) {
    if(!names.containsKey(uri))
        names.put(uri, new HashSet<String>());
    names.get(uri).add(hash);
}
```

But I'm at a dead end, because it's impossible to understand for which file I'm displaying the image, as generate only takes imageURI as parameter and more hashes can belong to the same uri.

How could I circumvent this issue?

Comment: it's not really clear to me, so you want the track_name.mp3 as key of the hash, and the track_name.jpg as value? if this is the case, just add album_name to the key [album_name_terack_name.mp3=track_name.jpg], so you can distinguish tracks with the same name, and having same value is no problem

Comment: @Yazan no. Two different files can have the same image uri (i.e. same album cover), I store for each uri a set of hashes, hashes are SHA1 of absolute path of the mp3 file, so that I know that the given uri is used by some files. When calling generate it should return the name of the mp3 but with png extension. But since `generate` only takes the uri as parameter, how do I know for which file I'm displaying the image? In other words, the same URI should load a different image according to the file that I'm displaying the cover for.

Comment: ok, why not use the other way around? use the track_name.mp3 as key, this way, the hash can be the same (which have same image) unless user changed the image, so that entry named (track_name.mp3) will have new hash (image)

Comment: @Yazan because generate has the uri as parameter, so the uri is the key, the files using the uri are the values.

Comment: ok, i got it now, sorry i realized it's related to the image loader :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution for this.

Whenever I call my `ImageLoader` instance to show an image, I use

```
if (uri != null && !uri.isEmpty()) {
    uri = Uri.parse(uri).buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("myhashkeyparameter", "myHashValue").toString();
}
mImageLoader.displayImage(uri,mImageView);
```

This code will append to a vaild uri a query parameter, the uri will become:

```
http://someuri/image.jpg?myhashkeyparameter=myHashValue
```

Then in the `FileNameGenerator`'s `generate` method I can use

```
String hash = Uri.parse(imageUri).getQueryParameter("myhashkeyparameter");
```

to retrieve the wanted file without relying on using the imageUri as key.

**Full code:**

```
@Override
public String generate(String imageUri) {
    if(imageUri==null||imageUri.isEmpty()) return "";
    if (imageUri.startsWith("file:///")) {
        return FilenameUtils.removeExtension(Uri.parse(imageUri)
                .getLastPathSegment()) + "."+ext;
    }
    String hash = Uri.parse(imageUri).getQueryParameter("myhashkeyparameter");
    if(null==hash||hash.isEmpty()) return "";
    if(Data.currentFiles.containsKey(hash)){
     return FilenameUtils.removeExtension(Data.currentFiles.get(hash).getName())+".png";
    }
    else return "";
}
```

You just have to be careful that the string used as queryparameter is not already used in the http URL, so avoid traditional names like name,hash,h,title and so on.